# Troubleshooting apache beam pipeline import errors [BoundedSource objects is larger than the allowable limit]

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam

I have a bunch of text files (~1M) stored on google cloud storage. When I read these files into Google Cloud DataFlow pipeline for processing, I always get the following error:

```
Total size of the BoundedSource objects returned by BoundedSource.split() operation is larger than the allowable limit
```

The trouble shooting page says:

> You might encounter this error if you're reading from a very large number of files via TextIO, AvroIO or some other file-based source. The particular limit depends on the details of your source (e.g. embedding schema in AvroIO.Read will allow fewer files), but it is on the order of tens of thousands of files in one pipeline.

Does that mean I have to split my files into smaller batches, rather than import them all at once?

I'm using dataflow python sdk for developing pipelines.

Comment: I am not sure why people voted to close this question. It's a very reasonable issue that people fairly often encounter when programming with Apache Beam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting your files into batches is a reasonable workaround - e.g. read them using multiple ReadFromText transforms, or using multiple pipelines. I think at the level of 1M files, the first approach will not work. It's better to use a new feature:

The best way to read a very large number of files is using [ReadAllFromText](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py#L357). It does not have scalability limitations (though it will perform worse if your number of files is very small).

It will be available in Beam 2.2.0, but it is already available at HEAD if you're willing to use a snapshot build.

See also [How can I improve performance of TextIO or AvroIO when reading a very large number of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362108/how-can-i-improve-performance-of-textio-or-avroio-when-reading-a-very-large-numb) for a Java version.

Comment: It doesn't look like this would work with Cloud Storage. Beam tests it with a Create PColl here: https://github.com/kasakun/GAE-Data-Flow/blob/eceb50b5be353ff0f6d86dd5a95b78b9d8d13e3a/virtual-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/textio_test.py but I can't find usage with Google Cloud. Any examples would be helpful.